# Oracle SQL: Using LAG when the current row is missing

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have a table from which I'm trying to extract information using a LAG function.

| Type | Date | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 01 | 1 |
| A | 02 | 2 |
| B | 01 | 3 |

I'm trying to get lines by Type with the Value from this month and the month before that, so ideally:

| Type | Date | Value M | Value M-1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 02 | 2 | 1 |
| B | 02 | 0 | 3 |

```
SELECT
Type,
Date,
Value as Value M,
LAG (Value,1,0) over(PARTITION BY Type ORDER BY Date) as Value M-1
FROM Table
```

Except that, of course, because there is no line for Type B and Month 02, I don't get a line for Type B.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I don't understand.   Your query does no filtering, but your results have only two rows, not three.

Comment: If `Date` is a column of data type `date`, then show dates in your examples, not strings like `01` and `02`. (Those are strings, not numbers; there is a number "1", "01" is not a number.) We will answer your question as posted and then you will come back and change the question, because the solution works for integers or for strings but you can't directly translate it to dates. Separate from that: the solution will very likely be based on partitioned outer join, and will have nothing to do with LAG or any other analytic function. Don't make your attempted answer part of the question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yep, well caught, my result should have had 3 rows.

Comment: @mathguy Actually my Date column is a string, formatted "YYYYMM". I did end up using a LAG: the trick was in reconstructing a whole table with no missing lines.

Answer (score 0):

A simple lag probably won't do the trick, because you need to construct a record for the last month if it doesn't exist for a given type. If your date is stored as an integer as in the sample data, a pattern like this is something to consider. If it's stored as a date, you'll need to have some kind of ranking baked in to the join or extract(month from date) - 1 (being careful about January), but this should give the gist.

```
WITH TYPE_LATEST_MONTH AS 
  ( SELECT DISTINCT
           TYPE,
           (SELECT MAX(DATE) FROM TABLE) AS LATEST_MONTH
      FROM TABLE
  )
SELECT TLM.TYPE,
       TLM.LATEST_MONTH AS DATE,
       COALESCE(TLM.VALUE_M, 0) AS VALUE_M,
       COALESCE(TLM_PREV.VALUE_M, 0) AS VALUE_M_MINUS_1
  FROM TYPE_LATEST_MONTH TLM
  LEFT
  JOIN TABLE TBL
    ON TLM.Type = TBL.Type
   AND TLM.LATEST_MONTH = TBL.DATE
  LEFT
  JOIN TABLE TBL_PREV
    ON TLM.Type = TBL_PREV.Type
   AND TLM.LATEST_MONTH = TBL_PREV.DATE - 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately I couldn't use it wholesale, because looking at it more closely the table is truncated in the step before and therefore I have to generate the entire history again, but this gave me the idea I needed to do that.

In my request, I do a crossjoin on distinct date and distinct type, left join this to the table to get the values, and then do a lag on the result. I managed to inadvertently correct a bug in the process, so it's all good :D